# Kubernetes lifecycle: preStop wait till finish processing

Tags: kubernetes

I'm working on Python application which is deployed as "Deployment" on k8s. The application scales up based on SQS messages number.
When messages count is zero, the pods are terminated without completing processing.
How to allow a pod to continue processing till finish running request processing based on memory and cpu usage?

Comment: Kubernetes [sends your Pod SIGTERM](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination) and waits for it to shut down; do you handle that signal?

Comment: Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further.<br>

Answer (score 1):

To allow a pod to continue processing till finish running request processing you can use below suggestions:

1.Use prestop and graceful shutdown to delay the termination of pod, Resulting:

- Application will wait a few seconds and then it stops accepting new connections.
- An application will wait until all requests are complete. And close all idle keepalive connections.

You can find more information about it in below blogs:

- [Blog - Graceful shutdown](https://blog.palark.com/graceful-shutdown-in-kubernetes-is-not-always-trivial/) by Ilya Andreev with NGINX example.
- [Blog Graceful shutdown](https://ubuntu.com/blog/avoiding-dropped-connections-in-nginx-containers-with-stopsignal-sigquit) by Robin Winslow.

2.You can use HPA to scale the deployment based on memory and cpu usage, so that one pod will remain active to take requests. You can find info related to scaling deployment via CPU and Memory in this [blog - HPA](https://granulate.io/blog/kubernetes-autoscaling-the-hpa/#:%7E:text=of%20the%20cluster.-,HPA%20Example%3A%20Scaling%20a%20Deployment%20via%20CPU%20and%20Memory%20Metrics,-The%20following%20is) authored by Naom Salinger.

3.In addition, you can also use [Horizontal pod autoscaling based on the metrics of Message Queue for RabbitMQ](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/en/container-service-for-kubernetes/latest/horizontal-expansion-of-containers-based-on-rabbitmq-indicator).

Comment: This means that it has a specific time to stop. What if the request requires more time then added to the template?

Comment: Using prestop and graceful shutdown pod will wait a few seconds and then it stops accepting new connections.As you mentioned "wait a few seconds and then it stops accepting new connections", in that case I think you need to run one pod continuously by using HPA, so that your pod can continue processing requests until they complete processing, without considering the number of SQS messages.